# Components required in Sybase unwired platform

Tags: sybase

I have an requirement to gather the components required to build an application in Sybase unwired platform, I am completely clueless as I suppose that it's a new platform introduced.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sybase  Unwired Mobility Platform if you are targeting the Mobile development . Its licensed though from SAP .
Link : http://sybase-unwired-platform.software.informer.com/2.1/ for free trial

Plus SCC  for registration of your mobile devices .

Plus Afaria application from SAP if you wanna track your devices .

Answer (score 0):

It's a complex platform too.  In order to best determine what components you need you should provide more detail on what you are trying to do.  What devices are you targeting, and what do you want to accomplish with them?